# Preserve EXIF + rotate Image in ios using ALAssetRepresentation

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, uiimage, exif

Hi I am having trouble uploading a photo from CameraRoll, preserving EXIF and at the same time rotate the image so up is up and down is down...

So far I have managed to upload image with EXIF intact but then I will loose orientation and on the web the image will sometimes lay down.  I can also rotate image in the app after making it an UIImage and using samplecode found on stackflow but then I will loose the EXIF.

For getting image from Photoalbum whit EXIF i use this:
`    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];`
```

If I preserve the image as NSdata all the way EXIF is intact. If I make it UIImage EXIF is lost. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

/knut

Comment: I have also tried to rotate the uiimage and after write it back to NSdata again together with EXIF which were cached separately as NSDictionary but still didn't find a sollution to write EXIF data to image that actually worked in iOS...